# Where is the third farmer in New York?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Unfortunately this game is not free of bugs.  In this case, markers disappear and never show on the map so it's hard to locate some targets or fast travel targets (forts, underground entrances, etc.).  One that is very annoying is one of the assassin liberation missions in New York Northern District.  There are three farmers that need protection but only two markers appear for them.

I've gotten two already and I believe they were here:

[image: first two farmers]

**Where's the third farmer?**

This mission is preventing me from getting my last assassin recruit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to identify farmer locations is to look for crops that contain scarecrows.  But even then, they can still be hard to pick out.  Fortunately, the farmers are not too far off from each other.

[image: the third farmer]

He's just northeast of the second farmer in that screenshot.  You'll find your farmer there.

Answer (score 0):

That may be true in some people's game but in mine i found him near the tavern. Just above it to the right near a well in a triangle section of roads. Hope this helps others out if they don't find the third farmer in the above screenshot!